# How to add new items in a sliding menu?

Tags: android, slidingmenu, items

I'm trying to add a new title and 2 items bellow my items listed in my sliding menu, but I just can't figure out how to do it..

Here is my code for the title and the items:

```
private void _initMenu() {
        NsMenuAdapter mAdapter = new NsMenuAdapter(this);

        // Add Header
        mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header);

        // Add first block

        menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items);
        String[] menuItemsIcon = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items_icon);

        int res = 0;
        for (String item : menuItems) {

            int id_title = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string",
                    this.getPackageName());
            int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon[res],
                    "drawable", this.getPackageName());

            NsMenuItemModel mItem = new NsMenuItemModel(id_title, id_icon);
            if (res==1) mItem.counter=0; //it is just an example...
            if (res==3) mItem.counter=0; //it is just an example...
            mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
            res++;
        }
        // Add 2nd Header
        mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header2);
```

And how to add items? I tried with the codes under the first addHeader, but it is not doing anything.. the list remains the same.. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you have an Adapter, use:

```
mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The .notifyDataSetChanged is crucial to updating the display.

Comment: It's not working.. it gives null pointer at `mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());`